# XMLHTTP support in IE from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I need to know whether "[Enable native XMLHTTP support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhOBo.png)" option is enbaled in Internet Explorer.

How can I find out it from JavaScript?

Comment: I think you'd have to check that in javascript.

Comment: Yes, I mean in javascript. 
How can I do it?

Comment: You've tagged this [tag:jsp]: Java Server Pages have nothing to do with JavaScript. Is that tag an error?

Comment: Yes, it is. I just have JavaScript code in jsp file.

Answer (score 0):

Enable native XMLHTTP support means that the browser will not provide `MSXML.HttpRequest` but instead `window.XMLHttpRequest`.

There is no way you can control this from the server side(in jsp). However, You can still write a javascript check logic  around `MSXML.HttpRequest` and `window.XMLHttpRequest` objects. I let you write the actual logic yourself.

Comment: I try 
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {...} 
But it is always true even if the option is disabled

Comment: Its how Microsoft itself says to check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537505(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, I looked at it earlier. Thanks. 
But it doesn't work for modern versions of IE.